# Convert a list of dicts inside a column to another columns containing only it's values

Tags: python

I have the following columns in a dataframe:

Keyword - Movie - ID

Inside the 'keywords' column there there is *in one specified row* the following string:

```
'[{"id": 849, "name": "dc comics"}, {"id": 853, "name": "crime fighter"}, {"id": 949, "name": "terrorist"}, {"id": 1308, "name": "secret identity"}, {"id": 1437, "name": "burglar"}, {"id": 3051, "name": "hostage drama"}, {"id": 3562, "name": "time bomb"}, {"id": 6969, "name": "gotham city"}, {"id": 7002, "name": "vigilante"}, {"id": 9665, "name": "cover-up"}, {"id": 9715, "name": "superhero"}, {"id": 9990, "name": "villainess"}, {"id": 10044, "name": "tragic hero"}, {"id": 13015, "name": "terrorism"}, {"id": 14796, "name": "destruction"}, {"id": 18933, "name": "catwoman"}, {"id": 156082, "name": "cat burglar"}, {"id": 156395, "name": "imax"}, {"id": 173272, "name": "flood"}, {"id": 179093, "name": "criminal underworld"}, {"id": 230775, "name": "batman"}]'
```

## I used the following code to make a list of one of the rows as a test:

```
 #consider x as being the row content

    x = ast.literal_eval(x)
    y = []
    for i in x:
        y.append(list(i.values())[1])
    y

output = ['dc comics',
 'crime fighter',
 'terrorist',
 'secret identity',
 'burglar',
 'hostage drama',
 'time bomb',
 'gotham city',
 'vigilante',
 'cover-up',
 'superhero',
 'villainess',
 'tragic hero',
 'terrorism',
 'destruction',
 'catwoman',
 'cat burglar',
 'imax',
 'flood',
 'criminal underworld',
 'batman']
```

I intended to make a new column that, if the list created for that row contained the string 'superhero' return 1, else 0.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
row_data = eval(row) #row is your row data
# Checks if there are any words in key 'name' that contains the term superhero returns 1 if contains else 0
contains_superhero =  [1 if 'superhero' in row_data[i].get('name') else 0 for i in range(0,len(row_data))]
int(1 in contains_superhero) # would give 1 if True 0 if False
```

you can make a function of this and use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function to apply it to every row

```
dataframe['new_column'] = dataframe['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: function_name(x))
```

Comment: Ok, this will probably work, but in this case i just got the output of a specific row using the .iloc, how can I make a function that will go into the 'keywords' column and get the values for the row the function is currently in?

Comment: `def contains_superhero(row)
 row_data = eval(row)
 return  int(1 in [1 if 'superhero' in row_data[i].get('name') else 0 for i in range(0,len(row_data))])

dataframe['new_column'] = dataframe['keywords_column_name'].apply(lambda x: contains_superhero(x))`